# CFA with lavaan: Standard errors not computable

Tags: r, standard-error, confirmatory-factor, lavaan, identifiability

I am not that much experiencend in R and I want to run a CFA. The code is as follows:

```
 higher <- '
# First Order
co =~ co1 + co2 + co4 + co6 + co7 + co9 + co10 + co11 
ia =~ ia1 + ia2 + ia3 + ia4 + ia5 + ia7
dc =~ dc1 + dc2 + dc3 + dc4 + dc5 + dc8 + dc9 
capm =~ capm1 + capm2 + capm3 + capm4 + capm5
# Second Order
factor2 =~ co + ia + dc
# Higher Order
factorh =~ factor2 + capm '
#calculation
fithigher <- cfa(higher, data=semdata, estimator="ml", bounds = T)
summary(fithigher, standardized=T, fit.measure=T, rsquare = TRUE)
semPaths(fithigher, "std", intercepts=FALSE, residuals = F)
```

Unfortunately, the after fithigher <- cfa(...) the following error is produced:

```
Warning message: In lav_model_vcov(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats,  : lavaan WARNING:
Could not compute standard errors! The information matrix could
not be inverted. This may be a symptom that the model is not
identified.
```

Can anybody help me to solve this issue? Thank you very much in advance.

The results of summary() as as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Or this: [lavaan WARNING: could not compute standard errors!](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159450/lavaan-warning-could-not-compute-standard-errors)